# Creating convenient type

Tags: haskell

I am beginning with Haskell. I have a situation where it is convenient to work the following type synonyms:

```
type Adult = Int
type Youth = Int
```

However I can not overload functions on `Adult` and `Youth` even if they had been synonyms for different types so have to have two seperate versions of functions eg. `doSomethingForAdult` and `doSomethingForYouth` , so next I tried

```
data Person = Adult Int | Youth Int
```

Then I can pattern match and use a single version of functions,
but then I loose the option of using the `Adult` and `Youth` as types in functions declarations which is convenient. Is there a middle way ? I looked at `Either`, but from the description in tutorials it seems this would be misuse ? Something similar to a small type hierarchy with `Person` at the root and `Youth` and `Adult` derived and still being synonyms for `Int` would be perfect but I can not figure out how.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see how that would be a misuse of `Either`. Just as `(,)` is a generic [product type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type), `Either` is perfectly acceptable as a generic [sum type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), i.e. anything of the form:

```
data T = T1 A | T2 B C
```

...can be thought of algebraically as `A + (B * C)`, which is equivalent to `Either A (B, C)`.

On the other hand, if you want to distinguish between `Adult` and `Youth`, using synonyms for the same actual type can be counterproductive; they're just transparent aliases. An alternate approach would be to use `newtype`s, like this:

```
newtype Adult = Adult Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read, Num) 
newtype Youth = Youth Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read, Num)
```

Adjust the `deriving` clause to taste; I added `Num` here because the underlying type is numeric, but if all you want is a unique identifier then adding or multiplying them doesn't make sense. At this point you can then use a sum type for `Person` if you like, or define a type class to get proper overloading:

```
class Person a where 
    -- (etc...)

instance Person Adult where -- ...
instance Person Youth where -- ...
```

Any functions defined in `Person` are then effectively overloaded on `Adult` and `Youth`, letting you [dispatch based on type the way "overloaded" functions in other languages do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad-hoc_polymorphism).

Comment: But `Either` isn't a very descriptive name for a specific thing such as adult/youth, and it's almost frequently used for wrapping some type with the possibility of an error.

Comment: @delnan: It's exactly as descriptive as required and not an iota more; `Either Adult Youth` is, indeed, either an `Adult` or a `Youth`. On the other hand, the same sum type named `Person` implies semantic exhaustiveness, that there are no additional cases like `Infant` or `Senior` or such. I actually dislike `Either` for errors precisely because that *should* have a better description than `Either`, and its by-convention use of `Left` for the error case.

Answer (score 4):

Are you wanting a `typeclass`?

```
data Adult = Adult Int
data Youth = Youth Int

class Person a where
  doSomething :: a -> b

instance Person Adult where
  doSomething (Adult i) = ...

instance Person Youth where
  doSomething (Youth i) = ...
```

This is the typical manner of overloading function in Haskell.  The typeclass, `Person`, has a single function, `doSomething :: a -> b`.  Each data type you want to be an instance of `Person` can have its own, separate, implementation.  If you want the underlying implementation to be the same then just use another function, `doSomethingGlobal :: Int -> b` and let each instance equal this new function.

Answer (score 1):

You can have both:

```
type Adult = Int
type Youth = Int

data Person = Adult Adult | Youth Youth
```

Data constructors are in a separate namespace from types so there is no conflict here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to just add the type synonym

```
type Person = Int
```

and you are able to give types to functions that work both, for Adults abd Youth, like

```
doSomething :: Person -> ...
```

(and you keep the possibility to use `Adult` and `Youth` in other type signatures)

Comment: This is the C way, but Haskell can do better.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make `Person` polymorphic:

```
data Person a = Person a Int
```

With this definition you can write general functions on `Person` level that don't care about the concrete value of `a`:

```
getInt :: Person a -> Int
getInt (Person _ i) = i 

incInt :: Person a -> Person a
incInt (Person p i) = Person p (inc i)
```

Then you can define "tags" to substantiate a `Person`:

```
data Adult = Adult
data Youth = Youth
```

Now you can write functions for a specific type of `Person`

```
rock :: Person Youth -> String
rock (Person Youth k) = "I rock until " ++ show k ++ " in the morning!!!"
```